# in loopback nodejs, nobody can create shop details through shop model

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

nobody is allowed to create directly through shop model
only admin can create shop through user/id/shop

by using ACL, I deny creating details in shop model. but I don't know how to create shop through admin only

```
"acls": [
    {
      "principalType": "USER",
      "principalId": "admin",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "create"
    },
    {
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$everyone",
    "permission": "DENY",
    "property": "create"
    }
]
```

thanks in advance

---

this is my script.js,

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  var User = app.models.User;
  var Role = app.models.Role;
  var RoleMapping = app.models.RoleMapping;
  debugger;
  User.create([
    {username: 'admin', email: 'admin@gmail.com', password: 'admin'},
  ], function(err, users) {

//create the admin role
Role.create({
  name: 'admin'
}, function(err, role) {


  role.principals.create({
    principalType: RoleMapping.USER,
    principalId: users[0].id
  }, function(err, principal) {
    //cb(err);
  });
});


});
}
```

but still i got authorization error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to create a `Shop` as an admin through `User` model (`POST /users/{id}/shops`), you also need to set correct ACL on `User`. I'm assuming you've set relations between these two models correctly and you've created an admin role.

*user.json (relevant part)*

```
"acls": [
  {
    "accessType": "WRITE",
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "admin",
    "permission": "ALLOW",
    "property": [ "__create__shops" ]
  }
]
```

You can find more related information in official LoopBack [docs](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Accessing-related-models.html).

Comment: authorization error. this is user.json                                                       {
  "name": "user",
  "plural": "users",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "shops": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "shop",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
    
  },
  "acls": [
   {
    "accessType": "WRITE",
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "admin",
    "permission": "ALLOW",
    "property":  "__create__shops" 
  }
],
  "methods": {}
}

Comment: Is a `Role` with a name `admin` created? Is a correct `RoleMapping` between your user and admin role created? Are you logged in as this user?

Comment: if I set, "principalid":$everyone, I can create a shop, i think the issue in admin role

Comment: Please set a foreignKey (for example to userId) in your `shops` `hasMany` relation in user.json. I've just quickly built your scenario and it works for me.

Comment: sorry. I don't know how to create rolemapping between user and admin

Comment: You can do it e.g. in a boot script as illustrated in [docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-and-using-roles.html)